# Excel, working out with cells

Tags: excel

i have some data on excel and i have on column H a list of solutions and on column G a target box that moves from 0 to 100, and i already have a code to generate the solutions in column H , but i want a code to check the target value on column G and checks column H for the nearest solution number and then puts the answer on column I and highlights it.

thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: show us what you've already built so that we can help you on your code

Answer (score 0):

You could do without macro, using a service column, say J, and conditional formatting:

1. on column I place the formula `=MAX(J$1:J$100)-J1` and copy/fill till row 100
2. similarly fill service column J with formula `=ABS(G1-H1)`
3. use conditional formatting in column I to highlight where value=0

You probably will need other function names, because spreadsheets use localized interfaces. For instance, for my test I used LibreOffice in Italian...

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the 'solutions' are positive numbers. If these solutions are arranged in **ascending order**, then you can use the following formula. If not, one solution can be to use a helper column to sort the values in ascending order.

Let your list of solutions in column H be from `H1:H100`, and your target box is in cell `G1`.
Then you can copy the following formula to the cell you want.

```
=IF(MAX(H1:H100)<=G1,MAX(H1:H100),IF(INDEX(H1:H100,1+MATCH(G1,H1:H100))-G1>G1-INDEX(H1:H100,MATCH(G1,H1:H100)),INDEX(H1:H100,MATCH(G1,H1:H100)),INDEX(H1:H100,1+MATCH(G1,H1:H100))))
```

Replace `H1:H100` everywhere in the above formula, with the range in which solutions are present in ascending order. Also, replace `G1` everywhere with the address of the cell with the target value.

If solutions are not in an ascending order, then you can use a **helper column**. You use one extra column for sorting the solutions into an ascending order. If your solutions are present in `H1:H10`, then in cell `I1`, you can enter the following formula.

```
=IF(ISERROR(SMALL($H$1:$H$100,ROW()-ROW($I$1)+1)),"",SMALL($H$1:$H$100,ROW()-ROW($I$1)+1))
```

Replace `$H$1:$H$100` in the formula with the range in which solutions are present. Also, replace `$I$1` with the cell address of the same cell where you are copying this formula. Here, since I am copying this formula into `I1`, I have used `$I$1`.

Now copy this formula down till where you have the solutions, e.g. for this example, you will copy it down upto `I100` since your solutions are from `H1:H100`.

Now in the previous formula, replace `H1:H100` with `I1:I100`, as this new list is sorted in an ascending order.

If this is not what you are looking for, maybe you could give me some more details, as your question is not very clear. Hope this helps.

P.S. : You can add the highlighting later, if you get the value that you require.